# c++ std::forward on the container calling operator[]

Tags: c++

In the book "Effective modern C++", at the item 3 there is written this piece of code:

```
template<typename Container, typename Index>
decltype(auto)
authAndAccess(Container&& c, Index i)
{
  authenticateUser();
  return std::forward<Container>(c)[i];
}
```

I don't understand why you call `std::forward`? If `c` is an rvalue reference, what does it change to call the `operator[]` on a rvalue instead on a lvalue? For me `c[i]` should be enough.

PS: I understand the purpose of `std::forward` when the variable is a parameter of a function as:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Ts&&... params)
{
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Ts>(params)...));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s possible that operator[] for Container has been overloaded for rvalues and lvalues.

```
auto Container::opeartor[](int i) && -> Container::value_type&;
auto Container::opeartor[](int i) & -> Container::value_type&;
```

If so, we want to make sure that if c was initialized with an rvalue, we call the rvalue version of operator[] on c. It’s certainly not common to overload operator[] to behave differently for lvalues and rvalues, but it’s possible, so in truly generic code, we need to apply std::forward to c before forwarding it to operator[].

Comment: I think compiler knows that c is rvalue ref, your answer would be applicable if && are in template parameters, or am I missing something?

Comment: c becomes a lvalue after the variable is set.